# Find CDF of constant derived random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a problem where I'm asked to find the CDF, PDF, and expected value of a function $f_Y(y)$ where:

$$F_X(x) = \cases{
 0, & x < -1 \cr
 x/3 + 1/3, & -1 $\le$ x < 0 \cr
 x/3 + 2/3, & 0 $\le$ x < 1 \cr
 1, & 1 $\le$ x
}$$

and $Y = g(X)$ where:

$$g(X) = \cases{
 0,& X < 0\cr
 100,& X $\ge$ 0
}$$

I have found $f_X(x) = 1/3 + 1/3\cdot\delta(x), -1 \le x \le 1$, but I'm not sure how to combine that with a constant Y, where Y doesn't seem to be a valid PDF in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\mathsf P(Y{=}y)=\begin{cases}\mathsf P(X{<}0)&:& y=0\\\mathsf P(X{\geq}0)&:& y=100\\0&:& \textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

Well, indeed, this will not have a proper probability density function, as its support consists of two massive points.

However, that did not prevent you from denoting a probability density function for $X$ which had one massive point at $x=0$ , denoted using the delta function times the point's probability mass of $1/3$.

So ... use two delta functions and the appropriate probability masses.